# How to get <text> tag from an html document using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can i get the `<text>` tag from an html document using beautiful soup for [Abbot lab 10k filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746919000624/a2237733z10-k.htm)

I want to extract tag names of all children of `<text></text>` tag using below code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url ='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746919000624/a2237733z10-k.htm'
htmlpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, "html.parser")
all_text = soup.find('text')
all_tags = all_text.contents
all_tags = [x.name for x in all_tags if x.name is not None]
print(all_tags)
```

but some how the output i am getting for the above code is `['html']`.

> Expected output:
>   `['p','p','p','p','p','p','div','div','font','font', etc......]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector (for printing **all** children of tag text):

```
for child in all_text.select('text *'):
    print(child.name, end=' ')
```

Prints:

```
br p font font b p font b br p font b div div ...
```

EDIT: For printing only **direct** children of tag text, you can use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746919000624/a2237733z10-k.htm'

htmlpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text, "lxml")

for child in soup.select('text > *'):
    print(child.name, end=' ')
```

Comment: @Shijith I updated my code. I'm using `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`

Comment: the issue was with the `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` which i was using to get the page, and the `html.parser` which i am using to parse . changed to `requests.get(url)` and parser to `lxml`, now its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code :

```
all_tags = all_text.contents
all_tags = [x.name for x in all_tags if x.name is not None]
print(all_tags)
```

TO:

```
all_tags = [x.name for x in all_text.findChildren() if x.name is not None]
print(all_tags)
```

[findChildren() more details](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html)

Comment: this will recursively go inside every child tag of `<text>`. i only want the name of all the child tags of `<text>` , excluding names of the children of the child tags.

Comment: @Shijith If you debug website source, you will see `<TEXT><HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY></TEXT>` DOM structure.

Comment: @Shijith You should scrap `body` tag of the child.